# Why is getter of a property caller before a setter is called when f:viewParam is the caller?

Tags: jsf, getter-setter, viewparams

Sorry for bad title, feel free to edit please.

So I have this piece of code:

```
<h:outputLink value="goodbye.xhtml">
    Go to goodbye!
    <f:param name="msg" value="test_one" />
</h:outputLink>
```

so when clicked, I will end up in **goodbye.xhtml** and the code for it is as follows:

```
<f:view>
    <f:metadata>
        <f:viewParam name="msg" value="#{blahBlah.parameter}"/>
    </f:metadata>
    <h:body>
        #{blahBlah.parameter}
    </h:body>
</f:view>
```

So when I have BlahBlah.java as follows:

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class BlahBlah {
    private String parameter;
    public String getParameter() {
        return parameter;
    }
    public void setParameter(String parameter) {
        if (parameter.equals("test_one")) {
            this.parameter = "test_one_modified";
            return;
        }
        this.parameter = parameter;
    }
}
```

I will see **test_one_modified** on **goodbye.xhtml** which is fine.

But when I modify BlahBlah.java as follows:

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class BlahBlah {
    private String parameter;
    public String getParameter() {
        if (parameter.equals("test_one")) {
            this.parameter = "test_one_modified";
        }
        return parameter;
    }
    public void setParameter(String parameter) {
        this.parameter = parameter;
    }
}
```

what I expect is to again see **test_one_modified** but instead I will get a nice **Null Pointer Exception**.

Isn 't

```
<f:viewParam name="msg" value="#{blahBlah.parameter}"/>
```

supposed to **set** BlahBlah.parameter?